# Checkbox break tableless form layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a form build with `<ul>` but I have a problem when I add checkbox somewhere.
It breaks whole layout.
Problem is somewhere in label styling but can't figure what?
[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vlada/rB8Lc/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your next row is stacking on top of the label floated to its left since the checkbox is not as high as the input field. One simple solution is to add another rule to your CSS to clear it:

```css
ul li { clear: left }
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hAMJp/)